# Pass input to an java program with linux scripting

Tags: linux, shell, autofill

I am working on a project where i have to create a shell script that can input stuff when i execute another shell script. For example i have a shell script call ABC.sh that will ask user to input 3 password in order for the service to start. Inside ABC is a script that will execute a java program which I can't get the source code, it only shows that the purpose of the script is to execute the java program. When the script is executed it will ask a user to input abc123 and press enter in order for the 2nd input to be fill in which is also abs123, after pressing the enter key a third input is needed which is also abc123. After pressing enter then it will start to run the java program.

My job here is to create a shell script that will execute ABC.sh and auto fill in abc123 three different times so that java program will start running.

Before i start working on the project i did a demo which is shown below. It works fine as inside Test.sh was a shell script that will read inputs.

```
./Test.sh <<EOF
abc123
abc123
abc123
EOF
```

Then i realize this method is only applicable to linux and linux passing so when i tried to shell script onto ABC.sh it never worked and when i check the log file it say password reading error.

The 2nd method i tried was to use mkfifo and pipe the input, what i did was

```
mkfifo path/srv-input

echo "abc123" >> path/srv-input
echo "abc123" >> path/srv-input
echo "abc123" >> path/srv-input

echo ^Z path/srv-input

tail -f path/srv-input | java program (Due to privacy problem i cannot show the whole path)

bg

disown $!
```

This method is not working as well. I tried to use set x to see whats happening and it only echo abc123 once and it stopped and stuck there.

I am looking for method that can help me with this project. My last resort will be give up and just hardcode the input in the java program.

Comment: Yeah it would be a lot easier if i can get my hands on the java program. However i will try to request for it and try the method you mentioned. The original solution you mentioned is the first method i did right?

Thank you for the help!

Comment: Oh, I should have read your initial paragraph more carefully the first time! (-8 . It's all about submitting passwords, not input data. Your plan might work (try a hard coded script calling the java first just to see i you can get it to work, then add the user-prompting wrapper). But most production programs are written to thwart password piping via std-in (not all of them, so try again). But you're mostly likely to need to read about the `expect` utility. AND you have to first confirm it is already installed or that your security team will allow it to be installed. ....

Comment: There are a lot o `expect` questions here on S.O. and it is pretty well documented/tutorialed elsewhere on the web, but it still may take some time to get it work. It's a little cranky (-; OR see if others elsewhere in your company have already figured this out. Consider how to make a TLDR statement fot the top of your Q. I understand why you have gone with narrative-mode for your Q, but recommend that you think about your readers and simplify the story line, focusing on requirements/code/results. Good luck.

Comment: yeah i read about expect before as it was one of the method that i discovered a while ago. Ir wasnt installed and i have not gotten permission to install it yet

Comment: @shellter thank you for the advice, i will try to write my question as straight forward as possible in the futrue. Of course questions that can be understand by readers